# How do I use a regular expression that looks for either a quote or an end of line?

Tags: regex

I want to match any string that starts with a quote and then ends with **either** an ending quote **or** an end of line (i.e. $). I tried this, but apparently the dollar sign doesn't work inside the brackets. Is this search possible?

```
//The string to search
var text = "\"something";

//The regex and an attempt at matching
var m = text.match(/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*["$]/);

//This is never called
if (m != null) alert(m);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([^\\]")+([^"]|\\")*([^\\]"|$)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will work for you:

```
/^"(?:[^"]*)("|$)/
```

It says

`^"`        Start of String followed by double quotes

`(?:[^"]*)` 0 or more characters which are not double quotes without capturing the group

`("|$)`     Either a double quote, or the end of the string

I'm not sure what you want exactly though. Are you looking for end of line or end of string? `$` means end of string. If you want to match end of line you want something more like `[\n\r]`

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
^"[^"]*("$|$)
```

Updated to exclude ecscaped quotes ( I don't see this requirement in the question):

```
^"([^"]|\\")*("$|$)
```

Sample: http://regexr.com?2u9nr

Comment: Thanks guys! What I finally came up with was: `/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*(?:"|$)/`

Comment: @Don Rhummy Did you try mine? Is it not meeting some of your requirements or wrong? Why the complex regex?

Comment: because yours doesn't account for a backslash + quote inside the quoted text. This should be a valid literal: `"some text with a \" inside"`

Comment: thanks for helping with this! The new version you isn't quite right though. I need it to match either a closing quote OR an end of line. So the quote can have other stuff after it, it doesn't have to be at the end. It just can't have a \ right before it. Maybe this? `([^\\]")+([^"]|\\")*([^\\]"|$)`